# How to show radio button value in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have radio buttons with the same name and same id, Which are dynamic data, I want to show these radio buttons values in input but when I am checking radio button only first radio button value is showing in input even if I check on second radio or third radio button.

I have three input type radio with the same name and same id but with different values, I am checking second and third radio button but it is showing only first radio button value in input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="red" id="myRadio">Red color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="blue" id="myRadio">Blue color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="green" id="myRadio">Green color


<input type="text" id="demo">

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myRadio").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").value = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I check on red color then its value should show on input type with id demo and if I check green or blue then it should show these value in input with id demo.

Comment: You can't have multiple `id`'s with the same value in HTML.

Comment: dynamic data is coming through php

Comment: sorry i will keep remember that

Comment: almost everyone solved my question if i do mark answer then other may get angry so i wll do later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant have more than one element with the same ID since **[IDs should be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)**. You should replace them with a class and then target the class name instead.

Also, avoid writing your JavaScript inline and use event listeners instead like this:

```js
/* JavaScript */

var radio = document.querySelectorAll(".myRadio");
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  
function checkBox(e){
 demo.value = e.target.value;
}

radio.forEach(check => {
 check.addEventListener("click", checkBox);
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" class="myRadio">Red color
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue" class="myRadio">Blue color
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" class="myRadio">Green color


<input type="text" id="demo">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the event to the `myFunction` function and use that to determine which radio button was clicked, here is an example:

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  document.getElementById("demo").value = event.target.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(event)" value="red" id="myRadio">Red color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(event)" value="blue" id="myRadio">Blue color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(event)" value="green" id="myRadio">Green color


<input type="text" id="demo">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="red" id="myRadio">Red color
    <input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="blue" id="myRadio">Blue color
    <input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="green" id="myRadio">Green color


    <input type="text" id="demo">

    <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
      document.getElementById("demo").value = x;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the use of `var x = value;`, you can simply pass *x* as the parameter!

Comment: @Mamun okay, I minified.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) must be unique in a document. You can use [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead because [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) can be used to identify more than one element.

**Please Note:** It is not good practice to use inline event handler.

You can use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns a static (not live) *NodeList* representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors. Then you can implement [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through all the elements to attach the event.

You can simply use [*this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword to refer the current *radio* button inside the function.

```js
const allRadios = document.querySelectorAll('.myRadio');
const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
allRadios.forEach(r => r.addEventListener('change', myFunction));
function myFunction() {
  demo.value = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" class="myRadio">Red color
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue" class="myRadio">Blue color
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" class="myRadio">Green color

<input type="text" id="demo">
```

If you do not want to modify the HTML, you can use attribute selector with [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) by using the *name* and *checked* attribute of the element.

```
document.querySelector('[name=colors]:checked').value
```

```js
const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelector('[name=colors]:checked').value;
  demo.value = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="red" id="myRadio">Red color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="blue" id="myRadio">Blue color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="green" id="myRadio">Green color

<input type="text" id="demo">
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first you should not have 3 element with the same id. Second you can have the checked radio button with jQuery. Here is your updated code:

```js
function myFunction() {
 
  document.getElementById("demo").value =  $('input[name=colors]:checked').val();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="red" >Red color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="blue" >Blue color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="green" >Green color


<input type="text" id="demo">

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to do it without jquery :

```js
function myFunction(event) {
var checked = null; 
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; elements[i]; ++i){
      if(elements[i].checked){
           checked = elements[i].value;
           break;
      }
}
  document.getElementById("demo").value = checked;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(event)" value="red" id="myRadio">Red color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(event)" value="blue" id="myRadio">Blue color
<input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction(event)" value="green" id="myRadio">Green color


<input type="text" id="demo">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Never use an ID more than once**.ID means unique.When we are using group of elements we should use class or any other common attribute. I ma using name of radiobutton group.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var colorSelected = document.querySelector('input[name="colors"]:checked').value;
 document.getElementById("demo").value = colorSelected;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="red">Red color</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="blue" >Blue color</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="colors" onclick="myFunction()" value="green" >Green color</label>


<p>Selected Color <input type="text" id="demo"></p>
```